Not able to collect flow data in another activity?
I am trying to collect flow data in activity A emitted from the Activity B but not receiving collect in Activity A,
Is flow emit data inside current activity only?
Emitting data from fragment view model added on activity B
launchOnMainDispatcher {
    IdMissionFwkManager._resultFlow.emit("{}")
    _effectFlow.emit(VstIdentificationEffect.Cancel)
}

Activity B flow collect receiving
IdMissionFwkManager.VzRegisterIdMissionFlow()
    .onEachCollect(owner = this) { result ->
        JSONObject(result)
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "IdMissionActivity: $result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

Activity A flow collect not receiving
IdMissionFwkManager.VzRegisterIdMissionFlow()
    .onEachCollect(owner = this) { result ->
        JSONObject(result)
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "MainActivity: $result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }


1. Use SharedFlow if not used already
Since Flow collects are synchronous, ensure that the emission in Activity B happens before the collection in Activity A. If Activity B is emitting data after Activity A has already started listening, there won't be any data for Activity A to collect. By using SharedFlow, you are creating a hot flow that always emits values to new collectors.
private val _resultFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
val resultFlow: SharedFlow<String> = _resultFlow

2. Use Proper Lifecycle Scopes
Make sure you are collecting the flow in the proper lifecycle scope of Activity A and Activity B. Using lifecycleScope or repeatOnLifecycle will ensure that the collection happens within the activity's lifecycle:
lifecycleScope.launch {
    IdMissionFwkManager.resultFlow
        .onEach { result ->
            // Handle the collected result
        }
        .collect()
}


Thanks alex, I am doing the same only, actually i am emits value from the fragment of my framework if that fragment is placed on  App activity then app is getting emits value but if fragment is on framework activity then App not getting emits.
